# Why is the orientation of $z$-orbital angular momentum vector definite for a one-electron system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, representation-theory

This is in reference to Quantum Physics of Atoms, Molecules, Solids, Nuclei and Particles by Robert Eisberg and Robert Resnick.

For an azimuthal quantum number $l$, the magnitude of the orbital angular momentum is given by $L = \sqrt{l(l+1)}\hbar$. For $l = 2$, the magnitude of the orbital angular momentum is
$L = \sqrt{2(2+1)}\hbar$, giving 5 $z$-components of the orbital angular momentum
$L_{z} = {-2\hbar, -1\hbar, 0, 1\hbar, 2\hbar}$ as is seen in the figure below.

[image]

The author says

> In any one of these states, the angular momentum vector is equally likely to be found anywhere on a cone symmetrical about the $z$-axis, and therefore has a definite $z$-component as well as a definite magnitude.

Admittedly, I am experiencing some difficulties understanding the author here despite re - reading multiple times what he wrote.

1.
If we suppose particle to be in the state $\sqrt{2(2+1)}$, does "equally likely to be found anywhere on this cone" implies an electron is equally likely to be found on the curvature of this cone spanned by an orbital angular momentum vector of magnitude $\sqrt{2(2+1)}$" preccessing about the the $z$-axis?

[image]

2.
If the orbital angular momentum is equally likely to be found anywhere on a cone symmetrical about the $z$-axis, for any of the 5 states, doesn't this mean there is an associated uncertainty with the $z$-component of the orbital angular momentum of the electron and thereby an associated uncertainty with $L$?

Comment: The cone is traversed by leaving the $z$ component of angular momentum constant and only varying the $x$ and $y$ components.

Comment: @ConnorBehan

For a given $l$, we have a definite $L$. But this means also a definite $L_{z}$ so for $l=2$, let the state of the z - component of the orbital angular momentum be $L_{z} = 2\hbar$.

So with $L_{z}$ held constant, varying only $L_{x}$ and $L_{y}$, this would be traversing the radii of the cone's base, isn't it? Have I understood you correctly?

Comment: The cone being referred to is the boundary... not the interior. Since $L^2 = 6$ and $L_z = 2$ in your example, $L_x$ and $L_y$ can only be varied subject to a constraint.

Comment: @ConnorBehan

The dots in the sketch represents the location on the boundary of the cone, not the interior.